# Starting and stopping QThread using Buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, interrupt, qthread

I have a live graphing gui which takes incoming data and processes it in a separate thread. I have read various posts about not reimplementing the run method and instead creating a worker and then using moveToThread.

The difference between my setup and others that I have seen is that there is no "finish" to the loop. The data can always be collected. In order to stop the data retrieval, you need to request an interruption. I am able to do that, but I can't start it over again. I believe it's because I initialize the thread before pressing the start button. However, if I move all of the thread initialization steps inside of a button press function, the stop button doesn't work anymore.

Here is some simplified code with a lot removed for simplicity. Please see the "Signals and Slots" part of the main thread to see where the worker and thread are made.

```
Class StatusThread(QObject):
    def __init__(self, signals, parent=None):
        super(StatusThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.signals = signals
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def initiate_loop(self):
        ### this is just a stand in method for testing the interruption
        count = 0
        while not self.thread().isInterruptionRequested() and count < 10:
            count += 1
            time.sleep(2)
            print(count)

class JetTracking(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, args=None, macros=None):
        super(JetTracking, self).__init__(parent=parent, args=args, macros=macros)
        self.signals = Signals()

        # assemble widgets
        self.setup_ui()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):

        return(QtCore.QSize(1000, 600))

    def setup_ui(self):

        # create layout
        self._layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self._layout)

        # give it a title
        self.lbl_title = Label("Jet Tracking")
        self.lbl_title.setTitleStylesheet()
        self._layout.addWidget(self.lbl_title)
        self._layout.addStretch(1)
        self.lbl_title.setMaximumHeight(35)

        # add a main layout for under the title which holds graphs and user controls
        self.layout_main = QHBoxLayout()
        self._layout.addLayout(self.layout_main)

        #######################################
        # make views/scenes to hold pydm graphs
        ####################################

        ################################
        # setup layout
        self.frame_graph = QFrame()
        self.frame_graph.setMinimumHeight(500)
        self.layout_graph = QVBoxLayout()
        self.frame_graph.setLayout(self.layout_graph)
        
        #########################################
        # set up user panel layout and give it a title
        #########################################
        self.frame_usr_cntrl = QFrame()
        self.frame_usr_cntrl.setMinimumHeight(500)
        self.layout_usr_cntrl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.frame_usr_cntrl.setLayout(self.layout_usr_cntrl)

        self.lbl_usr_cntrl = Label("User Controls")
        self.lbl_usr_cntrl.setTitleStylesheet()
        self.lbl_usr_cntrl.setMaximumHeight(35)
        self.layout_usr_cntrl.addWidget(self.lbl_usr_cntrl)

        ######################
        # make radiobutton for selecting live or simulated data
        ######################

        self.bttngrp = QButtonGroup()
        self.rdbttn_live = QRadioButton("live data")  # .setChecked(True)
        self.rdbttn_sim = QRadioButton("simulated data")  # .setChecked(False)
        self.rdbttn_live.setChecked(True)
        self.bttngrp.addButton(self.rdbttn_live)
        self.bttngrp.addButton(self.rdbttn_sim)
        self.bttngrp.setExclusive(True)  # allows only one button to be selected at a time

        ###########
        # main buttons!!!!
        ###############

        self.bttn_calibrate = QPushButton("Calibrate")
        self.bttn_calibrate.setStyleSheet("\
        background-color: yellow;\
        font-size:12px;\
        ")
        self.bttn_start = QPushButton("Start")
        self.bttn_start.setStyleSheet("\
        background-color: green;\
        font-size:12px;\
        ")
        self.bttn_stop = QPushButton("Stop")
        self.bttn_stop.setStyleSheet("\
        background-color: red;\
        font-size:12px;\
        ")

        # setup layout
        ##############
        self.frame_jjbttns = QFrame()
        self.layout_jjbttns = QHBoxLayout()
        self.frame_jjbttns.setLayout(self.layout_jjbttns)
        
        self.layout_jjbttns.addWidget(self.bttn_calibrate)
        self.layout_jjbttns.addWidget(self.bttn_start)
        self.layout_jjbttns.addWidget(self.bttn_stop)

        self.layout_usr_cntrl.addWidget(self.frame_jjbttns)
        ##############################

        # add frame widgets to the main layout of the window
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.frame_graph)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.frame_usr_cntrl)
    

        ###################################################
        # signals and slots
        ###################################################
    
        self.bttngrp.buttonClicked.connect(self.checkBttn)

        # create worker and thread
        self.worker = StatusThread(self.signals)
        self.workerthread = QThread()

        self.signals.status.connect(self.update_status)
        self.signals.buffers.connect(self.plot_data)
        self.signals.avevalues.connect(self.plot_ave_data)

        self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerthread)
        self.workerthread.start()

        self.bttn_start.clicked.connect(self.handle_start)
        self.bttn_stop.clicked.connect(self.handle_stop)
    
        ###################################################

    def handle_start(self):
        self.workerthread.start()
        self.worker.initiate_loop()

    def handle_stop(self):
        if self.workerthread.isRunning():    
            self.workerthread.requestInterruption()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loop in worker thread you can issue data retrieving continuosly until user pushes stop button and resume retrieving when user pushes start button

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

    retrieved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._i = 0

    def onRetrieve(self):
        def incAndEmit():
            self._i += 1
            self.retrieved.emit(self._i)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, incAndEmit)

class Ui(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    retrieve = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # ui initialisation
        startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("start")
        stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("stop")
        startButton.clicked.connect(self.onStartClicked)
        stopButton.clicked.connect(self.onStopClicked)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(startButton)
        layout.addWidget(stopButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        worker = Worker()
        thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.retrieve.connect(worker.onRetrieve)
        worker.retrieved.connect(self.onRetrieved)
        worker.moveToThread(thread)
        thread.start()

        self._thread = thread # protect from destroying by gc
        self._worker = worker # protect from destroying by gc
        self._stop = False

    def onStartClicked(self):
        self._stop = False
        self.retrieve.emit()

    def onStopClicked(self):
        self._stop = True

    def onRetrieved(self, data):
        # process data
        print("onRetrieved", data)
        if self._stop:
            return
        self.retrieve.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Ui()
    ui.show()
    app.exec()
```